# Get Day, Month, Year from Java Calendar instance

Tags: java, errorprone

I have an `Instant` derived from a Java `Calendar`, e.g. `c.toInstant()`, and now in a different location convert that to a custom Date object that needs a day of the month, month, and year. I tried:

```java
    if (instance.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH) && instance.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR) && instance.isSupported(ChronoField.YEAR)) {
      return new com.company.common.Date()
          .setDay(instance.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH))
          .setMonth(instance.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR))
          .setYear(instance.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
    }
```

But when I try to compile ErrorProne throws:

```
...impl/utils/DateUtils.java:21: error: [TemporalAccessorGetChronoField] TemporalAccessor.get() only works for certain values of ChronoField.
          .setDay(instance.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                              ^
```

I'm not sure why I can't find an answer for this anywhere, but after some searching I came up with nothing helpful -- though I probably missed something.

Comment: Hard to tell out of context. A [mre], please? Also remember to paste the full error message that you get.

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` hasn’t got any `toInstance` method. Did you mean `toInstant`? Can you avoid the `Calendar` class altogether and use a modern class like `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime` instead? That would be a great improvement since `Calendar` is troublesome and long outdated.

Comment: Ah good catch on the `toInstance` typo, thank you. I think I'll try to convince others (this is in a work context) to use `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: If you can’t avoid getting a `Calendar` object (say, `c`) from some legacy API, you may want to use `((GregorianCalendar) c).toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate())`. Both `LocalDate` and `ZonedDateTime` always support day, month and year.

Comment: `Instant.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)` always returns `false`, so your inner code would never get executed anyway.

Comment: Note that `Calendar` is deprecated legacy. Avoid it, if possible. The old date/time API was completely substituted by `java.time`, much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instant` is only a timestamp - it only provides seconds, millis and nanos.

If you start with a `Calendar` instance in the first place you should be able to simply use

```
calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

directly to fetch the date values and skip the conversion to Instant.

Note that in `Calendar` month is a zero-based value. You usually have to add one to get to value one would commonly expect.

If you prefer working with the newer time API you can fetch dates and time from a `ZonedDateTime` like

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId());

    zonedDateTime.getYear();
    zonedDateTime.getMonthValue();
    zonedDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
```

I don't see a direct advantage for the example given, beyond getting the "correct" value for month here directly.
It could be useful if you want to do any additional work with the date value beyond just reading its contents.

Generally speaking `ZonedDateTime` and all other types from the java.time package provide the more robust API and functionality compared to the older `Calendar` type. Therefore avoid the calendar type for any new code

Comment: Thanks @Roland. I'll do something like you suggest above.